# Cannot insert related data

Tags: baqend

I am trying to insert a record in one entity that has a List field that references another entity. The relation is supposed to be one-to-many.

```
var order = new DB.Order({
 order_code: '444',
 customer:DB.me,
 items:["/db/Item/0ecf15c9-ae4f-441a-ad14-d89d338d6303", "/db/Item/2caea632-5a8c-4101-a736-0bb2a4623fa3"],
});

order.insert();
```

Apparently inserting the referenced value in this format `["/db/Item/xxxxx", "/db/Item/xxxxx"]` will not work from javascript and the inserted value will be `[null, null]`, even though this format will work in the dashboard.

Any help in this regard will be appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

the SDK needs an instance of the object to correctly save the reference:

```js
var firstItem = new DB.Item();
var secondItem = new DB.Item();

var order = new DB.Order({
 order_code: '444',
 customer:DB.me,
 items:[firstItem, secondItem],
});

order.insert();
```

If you don't have the objects, you can get them by calling `DB.getReference`

```js
var order = new DB.Order({
 order_code: '444',
 customer:DB.me,
 items:[DB.getReference("/db/Item/0ecf15c9-ae4f-441a-ad14-d89d338d6303"), DB.getReference("/db/Item/2caea632-5a8c-4101-a736-0bb2a4623fa3")],
});

order.insert();
```